# Set height of certain div on click through jquery function in a-tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I'd like to expand a certain story-div when a button inside the div is clicked.

i.e: An overview of reviews shows only the first few sentences of a review. When a button is clicked the review expands to full height.

```
<div id="overview">
<div class="story">
    <div class="naam">John Doe</div>
    <div class="plaats">Washington DC, USA</div>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam at accumsan augue. Curabitur ac tortor felis. Quisque fringilla est at neque congue commodo. Proin metus libero, condimentum sed viverra et, pulvinar eget nisi. Donec viverra arcu ut ante adipiscing laoreet. In non tellus leo. Suspendisse ultrices eros quis odio fermentum id commodo ligula tempus. Nunc tincidunt suscipit dolor, nec tempus quam mattis non. Sed dapibus odio nec nisl ultricies vel commodo dolor sagittis.
    </p>
    <a class="readMore" href="javascript:openStory();" title="Read more">Read more &rsaquo;</a>
</div>
<div class="story">
    <div class="naam">John Doe</div>
    <div class="plaats">Washington DC, USA</div>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam at accumsan augue. Curabitur ac tortor felis. Quisque fringilla est at neque congue commodo. Proin metus libero, condimentum sed viverra et, pulvinar eget nisi. Donec viverra arcu ut ante adipiscing laoreet. In non tellus leo. Suspendisse ultrices eros quis odio fermentum id commodo ligula tempus. Nunc tincidunt suscipit dolor, nec tempus quam mattis non. Sed dapibus odio nec nisl ultricies vel commodo dolor sagittis.
    </p>
    <a class="readMore" href="javascript:openStory();" title="Read more">Read more &rsaquo;</a>
</div>
</div>
```

.story has a fixed height of 120px. I'd like to set its height to 'auto' with the openStory(); function.

```
function openStory(){
    this.parent('.story').css('height','auto');
}
```

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.readMore').click(function(event) { // Bind click event to all .readMore elements

  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default click action

  $(this) // Refers to the clicked .readMore element
    .parent() // Get parent element. Assuming it´s the .story element?
    .css('height', 'auto'); // set CSS rule. But why not use a CSS class?

});
```

..and replace `href="javascript:openStory();"` with `href="#"`.

Comment: it's better to replace `href="javascript:openStory();"` with `href="javascript:void(0);"` instead of `href="#"` to avoid sudden scrolling of the page

Comment: Thanks! But, if possible, I'd like to do this without the .click(); event. This way I can use the function for more elements throughout te website. If that's a stupid idea... please tell me :)

Comment: use a more explaining class name instead and use it where ever you need to.

Comment: Did use the .click()-method after all :)

Answer (score 0):

Used this in the end to open/close the div:

```
$('.review .story a.readMore').click(function(){
animatingElement = $(this).parent('.story');
if(animatingElement.hasClass('open')){
    animatingElement.removeClass('open');
} else {
    animatingElement.addClass('open');
}
});
```

Until Stefan came up with the toggleClass-function

```
$('.review .story a.readMore').click(function(){
animatingElement = $(this).parent('.story');
animatingElement.toggleClass('open');
});
```

That's the way to go.

Comment: Great! Try the `toggleClass` function as well; `animatingElement.toggleClass('open');` :)